# OBIEE 12.2.1.2 - Dashboard Customizations - Section Properties - Format Section

Tags: css, formatting, business-intelligence, dashboard, obiee

I want to resize the section properties of a text element within a dashboard. The text size should stay the same - I want to scale down the height of the green object (see pics).

Currently the element is displayed with the best fit as (here I want to reduce the height of the green object - to align it to the text):
[image]

Configuring a specific size adds an unwanted scrollbar. Apparently this appears as default due to the configured size of the text. However, the height appears still to be sufficient for the text size.

[image]

Ideas and suggestions are much appreciated - so far I was not able to resolve this issue with the custom css style options (HTML Only).

Comment: What settings did you touch on the text element's parent section and parent column? Because when you set nothing at all there is hardly any padding around dashboard-rendered text element:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2toep1vrs6xpla2/text_dashboard.png?dl=0

Edit: The .SectionTable has a padding of 3px all in all

Comment: Hi Christian, investigating the settings on the text element's parent section /column did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent. BTW it's always easiest to find out what's being set where just by using the F12 tools of your browser of choice.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of other users:

What settings did you touch on the text element's parent section and parent column? Because when you set nothing at all there is hardly any padding around dashboard-rendered text element: dropbox.com/s/2toep1vrs6xpla2/text_dashboard.png?dl=0 Edit: The .SectionTable has a padding of 3px all in all

Comment: Cool. I just moved it here so others searching SO can see that the thread contains an answer.